# Azure Function Log Screen in Portal Deprecated or Moved

Tags: azure, azure-functions

There used to be an Azure Functions screen that looked like this ...

[image]

I am wanting to know how you Used To Get to it.  I do not need to get to it today.  I am wanting to know how you used to navigate to this screen before it was removed or deprecated.  There was a time where you had to click "classic view" to see this screen.  I am suspicious that when the function was first or last deployed is relevant to the navigation to this screen, when it was reachable.

If anyone remembers what keywords or where the old menu items were that used to go to this screen for Azure Function Apps - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old monitor view retrieves data from the table in Storage Account specified by Application setting [AzureWebJobsDashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsdashboard). After Function 2.0 went GA, the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` is removed i.e. classic view was gone by default when we create new Function app, it's recommended to work with Application Insights now.

For v1 functions, to get the old view back, go to Application settings,

1. Delete `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`(if there is).
2. Add `AzureWebJobsDashboard` with a Storage Account Connection String, we could leverage the value of `AzureWebJobsStorage`.
3. Click the Monitor view, `Switch to classic view`.

For v2 functions, logs provided by ILogger are not sent to the table anymore, so I think the old feature has been deprecated completely.

Comment: Looks like Kudu  \LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\MyFunctionName   will get you to a log file with similar data.     But I am not sure if it is TraceWriter and Console are in these files. - or just tracewriter.

Comment: @SqlSurfer Yeah, kudu offers log files similar to Dashboard. And yes just tracewriter, console not works in Function.

Comment: @SqlSurfer the kudu is file is not getting updated. Lets say i trigger it 1 minute after the other, the file timestamp remains the same and also its not doing verbose level logging.